# Help a ruby noob understand class inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm trying to learn ruby by building a basic Campfire bot to screw around with at work. I've gotten pretty far (it works!) and learned a lot (it works!), but now I'm trying to make it a bit more complex by separating the actions to be performed out into their own classes, so that they can be easier to write / fix when broken. If you're interested in seeing all the (probably crappy) code, it's all [up on GitHub](https://github.com/gfontenot/wheelbot/tree/develop). But for the sake of this question, I'll narrow the scope a bit.

Ideally, I would like to be able to create plugins easily, name them the same as the class name, and drop them into an "actions" directory in the root of the project, where they will be instantiated at runtime. I want the plugins themselves to be as simple as possible to write, so I want them all to inherit some basic methods and properties from an `action` class.

Here is `action.rb` as it currently exists:

```
module CampfireBot
  class Action
    @handlers = {}

    def initialize(room)
      @room = room
    end


    class << self
      attr_reader :handlers
      attr_reader :room

      def hear(pattern, &action)
        Action.handlers[pattern] = action
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where `@room` is the room object, and `@handlers` is a hash of patterns and blocks. I kind of don't understand why I have to do that `class << self` call, but that's the only way I could get the child plugin classes to see that `hear` method.

I then attempt to create a simple plugin like so (named `Foo.rb`):

```
class Foo < CampfireBot::Action

    hear /foo/i do
        @room.speak "bar"
    end
end
```

I then have my plugins instantiated inside bot.rb like so:

```
def load_handlers(room)
  actions = Dir.entries("#{BOT_ROOT}/actions").delete_if {|action| /^\./.match(action)}
  action_classes = []
  # load the source
  actions.each do |action|
    load "#{BOT_ROOT}/actions/#{action}"
    action_classes.push(action.chomp(".rb"))
  end

  # and instantiate
  action_classes.each do |action_class|
    Kernel.const_get(action_class).new(room)
  end

  @handlers =  Action.handlers

end
```

The blocks are then called inside `room.rb` when the pattern is matched by the following:

```
handlers.each do |pattern, action|
  if pattern.match(msg)
    action.call($~)
  end
end
```

If I do `puts @room` inside the initialization of `Action`, I see the room object printed out in the console. And if I do `puts "foo"` inside `Foo.rb`'s `hear` method, I see `foo` printed out on the console (so, the pattern match is working). But, I can't read that `@room` object from the parent class (it comes out as a nil object). So obviously I'm missing something about how this is supposed to be working.

Furthermore, if I do something to make the plugin a bit cleaner (for larger functions) and rewrite it like so:

```
class Foo < CampfireBot::Action

    hear /foo/i do
        say_bar
    end

    def say_bar
        @room.speak "bar"
    end
end
```

I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'say_bar' for Foo:Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `hear` can be pulled out of the `class << self` block and changed to:

```
 def self.hear(pattern, &action)
   Action.handlers[pattern] = action
 end
```

to yield the exact same result. That also immediately explains the problem. `hear` Is a class method. `say_bar` is an instance method. You can't call an instance method from a class method, because there simply isn't an instance of the class available.

To understand the `class << self` bit, you'll have to do your own reading and experiments: I won't try to improve on what has already been said. I'll only say that within the `class << self .. end` block, `self` refers to the *eigenclass* or *metaclass* of the `CampfireBot::Action` class. This is the instance of the `Class` class that holds the definition of the CampfireBot::Action class.